# I Haven't Had the Pleasure

Tags: knowledge

If...

> I hurled a dream into the reservoir
>   But you shouldn't inquire why--my lips are sealed.
>   When my aforementioned action had consequences, I was gazing at you.
>   Move!

And...

> I'm looking to exchange Lust for my Persona
>   and buy a smack for pocket change.
>   I don't have what I wanted.
>   Again, move!

While...

> You couldn't tear your eyes away from me
>   and were wearing distressed clothes.
>   The evening was overly warm but breezy.
>   Now get back here!

...What's a recommended course of action for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should:

> **Call me maybe**, as in the song by Carly Rae Jepsen

I hurled a dream into the reservoir
But you shouldn't inquire why--my lips are sealed.
When my aforementioned action had consequences, I was gazing at you.
Move!

> I threw a wish in the well
>  Don't ask me I'll never tell
>  I looked at you as it fell
>  And now you're in my way

I'm looking to exchange Lust for my Persona
and buy a smack for pocket change.
I don't have what I wanted.
Again, move!

> I'd trade my soul for a wish
>  Pennies and dimes for a kiss
>  I wasn't looking for this
>  But now you're in my way

You couldn't tear your eyes away from me
and were wearing distressed clothes.
The evening was overly warm but breezy.
Now get back here!

> Your stare was holding
>  Ripped jeans, skin was showin'
>  Hot night, wind was blowin'
>  Where you think you're going baby?

And BTW,

> I figured these were the lyrics to some song but I couldn't figure out which one.  I had heard this song recently and as I was rereading this puzzle, all of a sudden Carly's voice "pennies and dime for a kiss" came into my head out of nowhere and helped me solve the puzzle.